# Fill column based on row and column names in other dataframe

Tags: r

I have one data frame (df1) that looks like this:

[image]

```
df1 <- structure(list(Station = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"), Date = c(
  "1/07/2022 15:45",
  "20/08/2022 23:50", "12/03/2023 21:26", "10/08/2022 13:26", "14/08/2022 13:10",
  "15/08/2022 15:26"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
  cols = list(Station = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  )), Date = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  ))), default = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_guess",
    "collector"
  )), delim = ","
), class = "col_spec"), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And another (df2) with dates as column names in a different format and with values for temperature on each day like this:

[image]

```
df2 <- structure(list(Station = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), `20220701` = c(
  24.1,
  22.5, 23.5, 22.3
), `20220810` = c(18.7, 13.4, 16.3, 12.2), `20220814` = c(
  21.4,
  18.9, 27.8, 25.6
), `20220815` = c(16.5, 21.7, 22.5, 28.4), `20220820` = c(
  23.6,
  23.4, 31.6, 24.4
), `20230312` = c(25.5, 17.5, 23.7, 22.1), `20230820` = c(
  32.6,
  12.2, 21.1, 29.4
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(
  cols = list(Station = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  )), `20220701` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `20220810` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `20220814` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `20220815` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `20220820` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `20230312` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `20230820` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  ))), default = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_guess",
    "collector"
  )), delim = ","
), class = "col_spec"), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would like to add another column to df1 with temperatures matched to the dates and stations in df2, like this:

[image]

```
structure(list(Station = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"), Date = c(
  "1/07/2022 15:45",
  "20/08/2022 23:50", "12/03/2023 21:26", "10/08/2022 13:26", "14/08/2022 13:10",
  "15/08/2022 15:26"
), Temperature = c(
  24.1, 23.6, 17.5, 16.3,
  27.8, 28.4
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
  Station = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  )), Date = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  )), Temperature = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  ))
), default = structure(list(), class = c(
  "collector_guess",
  "collector"
)), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The format of df2 is throwing me off and beyond my meagre R skills. Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Reshape `df2` to long, convert the dates to the same format, then do a join. For more help:  Since we can't run or test code based on images of data, please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you have tried and a snippet of your data or some fake data shared using `dput()`, e.g. create your example by running `dput(df1)` and copy the output into your post.

Comment: Thanks @stefan I have added the reproducible data as suggested.

Comment: Your structure for df2 has `Station = c("A", "A", "B", "D")` when the image appears to be `Station = c("A", "B", "C", "D")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With advent of new dplyr 1.1.0, you can also use [`closest`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/01/dplyr-1-1-0-joins/) like this

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy_hm(Date)) %>% 
  left_join(
    df2 %>% 
      pivot_longer(-Station, names_to = 'date', values_to = 'temp') %>% 
      mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date)),
    by = join_by(
      Station == Station,
      closest(Date >= date)
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Station Date                date        temp
#>   <chr>   <dttm>              <date>     <dbl>
#> 1 A       2022-07-01 15:45:00 2022-07-01  24.1
#> 2 A       2022-08-20 23:50:00 2022-08-20  23.6
#> 3 B       2023-03-12 21:26:00 2023-03-12  17.5
#> 4 C       2022-08-10 13:26:00 2022-08-10  16.3
#> 5 C       2022-08-14 13:10:00 2022-08-14  27.8
#> 6 C       2022-08-15 15:26:00 2022-08-15  22.5
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in my comment, one option to achieve your desired result would be to reshape `df2` to long, converting the date columns in both datasets to a proper date using `as.Date` and afterwards using a `left_join`.

Note: I fixed your example data which included two As in `df2` but no C.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

# Fix. Example data has two A, but no C
df2 <- df2 |> mutate(
  Station = LETTERS[1:4]
)

df2_long <- df2 |>
  pivot_longer(-Station, names_to = "Date") |>
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%Y%m%d"))

df1 |> 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")) |> 
  left_join(df2_long, by = c("Station", "Date"))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   Station Date       value
#>   <chr>   <date>     <dbl>
#> 1 A       2022-07-01  24.1
#> 2 A       2022-08-20  23.6
#> 3 B       2023-03-12  17.5
#> 4 C       2022-08-10  16.3
#> 5 C       2022-08-14  27.8
#> 6 C       2022-08-15  22.5
```

Answer (score 1):

A data.table solution which converts df2 to long format, makes the date format consistent and left joins df1 and df2_long.  This solution also keeps the time component of the Date variable in df1.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.table(
  Station = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
  Date = c("1/07/2022 15:45", "20/08/2022 23:50", "12/03/2023 21:26", 
           "10/08/2022 13:26", "14/08/2022 13:10", "15/08/2022 15:26"))

df2 <- data.table(
  Station = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
  `20220701` = c(24.1, 22.5, 23.5, 22.3), 
  `20220810` = c(18.7, 13.4, 16.3, 12.2), 
  `20220814` = c(21.4, 18.9, 27.8, 25.6), 
  `20220815` = c(16.5, 21.7, 22.5, 28.4), 
  `20220820` = c(23.6, 23.4, 31.6, 24.4), 
  `20230312` = c(25.5, 17.5, 23.7, 22.1), 
  `20230820` = c(32.6, 12.2, 21.1, 29.4))

# Convert to long
df2_long <- melt(df2, id.vars = "Station",
                 variable.name = "Day",
                 value.name = "Temperature")

# Use lubridate for both date columns
df1[, Date := dmy_hm(Date)]
df1[, Day := as_date(Date)]
df2_long[, Day := ymd(Day)]

# Left join the tables
df2_long[df1, .(Station, Date, Temperature), on = .(Day, Station)]
```

Result:

```
   Station                Date Temperature
1:       A 2022-07-01 15:45:00        24.1
2:       A 2022-08-20 23:50:00        23.6
3:       B 2023-03-12 21:26:00        17.5
4:       C 2022-08-10 13:26:00        16.3
5:       C 2022-08-14 13:10:00        27.8
6:       C 2022-08-15 15:26:00        22.5
```